# Python findall, regexp with "|" and grouping

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to implement [Pig Latin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_Latin) with Python.
I want to match strings which begins by a consonant or "qu" (no matter the case) so to find the first letters, so at first I was doing :

```
first_letters = re.findall(r"^[^aeiou]+|^[qQ][uU]", "qualification")
```

It didn't work (finds only "q") so I figured that i had to add the q in the first group :

```
first_letters = re.findall(r"^[^aeiouq]+|^[qQ][uU]", "qualification")
```

so that works (it finds "qu" and not only "q") !

But playing around I found myself with this :

```
first_letters = re.findall(r"{^[^aeiou]+}|{^[qQ][uU]}", "qualification")
```

that didn't work because it is the same as the first expression I tried I think.
But finally this also worked :

```
first_letters = re.findall(r"{^[^aeiou]+}|(^[qQ][uU])", "qualification")
```

and I don't know why.
Someone can tell me why ?

Answer (score 2):

Reverse the order of the rules:

```
>>> re.findall(r"^[qQ][uU]|^[^aeiou]+", "qualification")
['qu']
>>> re.findall(r"^[qQ][uU]|^[^aeiou]+", "boogie")
['b']
>>> re.findall(r"^[qQ][uU]|^[^aeiou]+", "blogie")
['bl']
```

In your first case, the first regex `^[^aeiou]+` matches the `q`. In the second case, since you've added `q` to the first part, the regex engine examines the second expression and matches `qu`.

In your other cases, I don't think the first expression does what you think it does (i.e. the `^` character inside the braces), so it's the second expression which matches again.

The first part of your 3rd and 4th patterns, `{^[^aeiou]+}` is trying to match a literal curly brace `{` followed by a `start-of-line` followed by one or more non-vowel characters, followed by a literal closing curly brace `}`. Since you don't have `re.MULTILINE` enabled, I'd assume that your pattern will be technically valid but unable to match any input.

Comment: Yeah I figured out that I could reverse the rules but I didn't understand why the thing with the braces worked, what does ^ insides do ?? I'm sorry I can't find the right word to look it up on Google.

Comment: You could add `(?: ... )` to your group so it doesn't capture, f.e. `r"^(?:[qQ][uU]|[^aeiou]+)"`

Answer (score 2):

You should put `qu` before `[^aeuio]`, because otherwise "q" gets captured by the class and fails to match. Besides that, `[Qq][Uu]` is not needed, just provide the case insensitive flag:

```
first_letters = re.findall(r"^(qu|[^aeiou]+)", "qualification", re.I)
```

Given that you're probably going to match the rest of the string as well, this would be more practical:

```
start, rest = re.findall(r"^(qu|[^aeiou]+)?(.+)", word, re.I)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `|` runs left to right, and stops at the first success.  So, that's why you found only `q` with the first expression, and `qu` with the second.

Not sure what your final regex does, particularly with regard to the `{}` expression.  The part after the `|` will match in qualification, though.  Perhaps that's what you are seeing.

You might find the `re.I` (ignore case) flag useful.